# postgres init : could not look effective user id : user does not exists

Tags: database, postgresql, operating-system, database-administration

I upgraded to postgres 9.6.0. 
I am not able to start a new database instance. 
On

`pg_ctl  -D /localscratch/sandeep/pgsql_sa_5579 init`

I get error

`initdb: could not look up effective user ID 21073: user does not exist`

I am not sure if this is OS setup issue or a database issue.
I am on CentOS release 6.8.

Comment: What OS are you on? Edit your post and add the OS in the tag please

Comment: When you upgraded did you mess with the OS at all? Is/was there a user #21073 in your /etc/passwd file? This may be a red herring, but it should be easy to rule out.

Comment: I don't have root permission on the OS. I am installing and running postgres as a user

Comment: @FoxCy: added os and tag

Comment: It seems passwords are maintained via ldap.

Comment: what you see when `who am i`?..

Comment: @vaoTsun  I see my login name

Comment: so grep you yor name from /etc/password ?.. do id match?..

Comment: linux says my user id is 21073 on the machine which is what the program is not able to lookup

Comment: @VaoTsun No hit with grep. I am not sure how /etc/passwd is being used.

Comment: well, when you run `initdb` - you create a cluster and thus plenty of files which need owner, thus I assume you need an effective OS user - thus it checks for /etc/password

Comment: You should still be able to read /etc/passwd even if you're not root.

Comment: I am able to read /etc/passwd. However there is no entry for users in /etc/passwd.

Comment: Hi @Sandeep! Did you solve the problem?

Comment: @Mikhail_Sam Very sorry, can't recall at all if this issue was resolved. Is your /tmp/password readable by the user running the postgres server?

Comment: @Sandeep thank you for response! I solved the problem - I used Postgres at Kubernetes and the solution was to set correct `runAsUser` option!